# Filter the list in scala based on the regular expression

Tags: regex, list, scala

I have a list in Scala as below.

```
val inputList :List[String] = List("Manager","VP", "12/09/2011","Access","10/11/2021 1:51 PM","Agent","Customer Contact date 07/23/2011", "Profile")
inputList: List[String] = List(Manager, VP, 12/09/2011, Access, 10/11/2021 1:51 PM, Agent, Customer Contact date 07/23/2011, Profile)
```

Now I want to ignore the list elements that only STARTS WITH a date. So when I filter out and print the list I should get it as the below.

```
Manager
VP
Access
Agent
Customer Contact date 07/23/2011
Profile
```

I tried as

```
scala>var finalList = List[String]()

scala> finalList =  inputList.filterNot(r => r.startsWith("[0-9]{1,2}[/][0-9]{1,2}[/][0-9]{4}"))
finalList: List[String] = List(Manager, VP, 12/09/2011, Access, 10/11/2021 1:51 PM, Agent, Customer Contact date 07/23/2011, Profile)
```

I still see elements starting with date. I tried different regex format as below and still see its not ignoring them. Is the regex I am using has any issue? I tried `scala> finalList =  inputList.filterNot(r => r.startsWith("\\d{1,2}[/]\\d{1,2}[/]\\d{4}")` and still see its not eliminating list elements that begin with date. Can i get some advise...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using startsWith does not take a regex. You could use `findFirstIn` and then filterNot the values that are nonEmpty.

You might use

```
val inputList :List[String] = List("Manager","VP", "12/09/2011","Access","10/11/2021 1:51 PM","Agent","Customer Contact date 07/23/2011", "Profile")
val rgx = "^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}".r
val finalList: List[String] = inputList.filterNot(s =>
  rgx.findFirstIn(s)
    .nonEmpty
)
finalList
```

Output

```
res0: List[String] = List(Manager, VP, Access, Agent, Customer Contact date 07/23/2011, Profile)
```

Or use filter with isEmpty

```
val finalList: List[String] = inputList.filter(s => rgx.findFirstIn(s).isEmpty)
```

Comment: It may be good to cache the compiled regex outside the lambda.

Comment: @The fourth bird ,Thanks for the response. I see its now working as expected.